Jetpack Compose Performance Issue | Horizontal Pager
I experience some jank in the UI when changing pages in the horizontal pager. Do you know what might be causing this issue? I've tried all the different ways for skipping recompositions, but none seem to help. Is there something wrong with the performance of the library itself (since it's still experimental)?
MarketAssetsView(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .height(screenHeight - 60.dp),
                        horizontalTabModifier = Modifier
                            .nestedScroll( remember {
                                object : NestedScrollConnection {
                                    override fun onPreScroll(
                                        available: Offset,
                                        source: NestedScrollSource
                                    ): Offset {
                                        return if (available.y > 0) Offset.Zero else Offset(
                                            x = 0f,
                                            y = -scrollState.dispatchRawDelta(-available.y)
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            }),
                        loginStatus = isUserLoggedIn,
                        assets = assets,
                        favoriteAssets = favoriteAssets,
                        getAssets = viewModel::getAssets,
                        getFavoriteAssets = bookmarksViewModel::getBookmarks,
                        stopRefreshingAssets = viewModel::cancelDataUpdates,
                        stopRefreshingFavoriteAssets = bookmarksViewModel::cancelDataUpdates,
                        refreshAssetsPeriodically = viewModel::refreshDataPeriodically,
                        refreshFavoriteAssetsPeriodically = bookmarksViewModel::refreshDataPeriodically,
                        selectedCategoryIndex = homeConfig.selectedCategoryIndex,
                        saveLatestSelectedCategory = screenConfigViewModel::saveLatestChosenCategory
                    )

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun MarketAssetsView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    horizontalTabModifier: Modifier,
    loginStatus: UserStatus,
    assets: Resource<List<Asset>>,
    favoriteAssets: Resource<List<Asset>>,
    selectedCategoryIndex: Int,
    getAssets: (String) -> Unit = {},
    getFavoriteAssets: () -> Unit = {},
    refreshAssetsPeriodically: (String) -> Unit = {},
    refreshFavoriteAssetsPeriodically: () -> Unit = {},
    stopRefreshingAssets: () -> Unit = {},
    stopRefreshingFavoriteAssets: () -> Unit = {},
    onTabChanged: (String) -> Unit = {},
    saveLatestSelectedCategory: (Int) -> Unit = {}
) {
  HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState,
            modifier = horizontalTabModifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
        ) { page: Int ->
            // if the page is the current screen, show the current resource
            when(page) {
                0 -> {
                    MarketAssets(
                        assetsResource = if(loginStatus == UserStatus.LoggedIn) favoriteAssets else assets,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        onTryAgainClicked = {
                            if(loginStatus == UserStatus.LoggedIn) {
                                getFavoriteAssets()
                                refreshFavoriteAssetsPeriodically()
                            } else {
                                val targetCategories = if(loginStatus==UserStatus.LoggedIn) categories[1].name
                                else categories[0].name
                                getAssets(targetCategories)
                                refreshAssetsPeriodically(targetCategories)
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
                else -> {
                    MarketAssets(
                        assetsResource = assets,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        onTryAgainClicked = {
                            val targetCategories = if(loginStatus==UserStatus.LoggedIn) categories[1].name
                            else categories[0].name
                            getAssets(targetCategories)
                            refreshAssetsPeriodically(targetCategories)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }

        }
}


Try this:

Use remember, I see some many data passing directly to the components.
Use derivedStateOf, why? should be used when your state or key is changing more than you want to update your UI
Try release apk, active R8; Since in debug mode you get many lag issue


The passed data is coming from my viewModel, so there is no need for remember with strong skipping enabled. I already tried testing the release build with R8 enabled, and it didn't work. I don't see a good reason for using derivedStateOf in my case since the function has to recompose with every change to the selectedCategoryIndex anyways. Any thoughts?

@SalmaKD Still I believe you need to manage your compose in efficient way, I think you make your screen recompose too many time, to detect that try layout inspector to check how many recompose you get

that's the thing! The entire horizontalPager is skipped when I see the layout inspector. Do you think there might be an issue with the Horizontal pager library itself? The Sunflower sample seems to have jank when scrolling in release build also although the code seems to have no issues.
